# How to make firebase's database for different users

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

guys I really need your help. I have been working a project that somewhat looks like a to-do list application for over a month now with Vue js and Firebase and Firestore. I have been able to design a sign in and sign up page so far to authenticate users before they can use this application. I used Firebase's storage to store every to-do the user has created in a store. But when I tried testing the application by logging in with different users i.e User A, User B, and User C. If User A adds a to-do to the list the to-do list is updated with the current to-do User A just added, but the issue here is that User B and User C are being able to see whatever User A  adds and this is happening to all the Users.
Please, I want to make whatever to-do any logged in user creates should only be seen by the creator of the to-do and no third party else.
This is how my firebase rule looks like

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But after I changed the rule in other to allow authenticated users read and write their data to

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
  // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
  // available in rules.
   match /users/{userId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

}

The created data were not showing and there was an error on my console
that read FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Read https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security.

Comment: That's the link for the Firebase Realtime Database. For Cloud Firestore the relevant documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication